# Poorly implemented two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (kstest2) in Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

Am I missing something obvious or Matlab's [`kstest2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html) is giving very poor *p*-values?
Under very poor I mean that I have the suspicion that it is even wrongly implemented.

Help page of [`kstest2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html) states that the function calculates asymptotic *p*-value, though I did not find any reference about which method is used exactly. Anyway, the description further states:

> asymptotic *p*-value becomes very accurate for large sample sizes, and is believed to be reasonably accurate for sample sizes n1 and n2, such that (n1*n2)/(n1 + n2) ≥ 4

---

**Example 1**

Let's take Example 6 from Lehman and D'Abrera (1975):

```
sampleA         = [6.8, 3.1, 5.8, 4.5, 3.3, 4.7, 4.2, 4.9];
sampleB         = [4.4, 2.5, 2.8, 2.1, 6.6, 0.0, 4.8, 2.3];
[h,p,ks2stat]   = kstest2(sampleA, sampleB, 'Tail', 'unequal');
```

`(n1*n2)/(n1 + n2) = 4` in this case so the *p*-value should be reasonably accurate.

Matlab yields `p = 0.0497`, while the solution given in the book is `0.0870`.
To validate the solution I used R, which I trust more than Matlab, especially in statistics.

Using [`ks.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) from `stats` package and [`ks.boot`](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/ks.boot.html) from `Matching` package:

```
ks.test(sampleA, sampleB, alternative = "two.sided")
ks.boot(sampleA, sampleB, alternative = "two.sided")
```

Both give `p = 0.0870`.

---

**Example 2**

Lets use `kstest2`'s own example to compare Matlab and R results for larger sample size:

```
rng(1);     % For reproducibility
x1 = wblrnd(1,1,1,50);
x2 = wblrnd(1.2,2,1,50);
[h,p,ks2stat] = kstest2(x1,x2);
```

This yields `p = 0.0317`. Now, using the same `x1` and `x2` vectors R gives `p = 0.03968`.
About 20% difference when very accurate result is expected `(n1*n2)/(n1 + n2) = 25`.

Am I missing, messing up something?
Is it possible that Matlab's `kstest2` performs so poorly as the examples indicate? What approximation, algorithm `kstest2` is using? (I can see the implemented code for kstest2, however a reference to book or paper would be much better to understand what is going on.)

I am using Matlab 2016a.

---

Lehman and D'Abrera (1975). [Nonparametrics: Statistical Methods Based on Ranks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387352120). 1st edition. Springer.

Comment: You'd probably get a better answer on CrossValidated

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks for the suggestion. I will wait some times here on Stackoverflow and if no answer received I will delete this question and re-ask on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the [correct test](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/kolmogorov_smirnov_test_2.html) to compare with R's `ks.test` in MATLAB or Octave would be `kolmogorov_smirnov_test_2`:

```
sampleA         = [6.8, 3.1, 5.8, 4.5, 3.3, 4.7, 4.2, 4.9];
sampleB         = [4.4, 2.5, 2.8, 2.1, 6.6, 0.0, 4.8, 2.3];

kolmogorov_smirnov_test_2(sampleA, sampleB)
```

> pval: 0.0878664

The difference appears to be the use of `ks` versus `lambda`, i.e.

```
ks   = sqrt (n) * d;
pval = 1 - kolmogorov_smirnov_cdf (ks);
```

versus

```
lambda =  max((sqrt(n) + 0.12 + 0.11/sqrt(n)) * d , 0);
pval = 1 - kolmogorov_smirnov_cdf (lambda);
```

I presume the different test statistics arise from the differences in the research papers cited by these 2 functions. If you want a deeper dive into the statistical theory you may want to reach out to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks! Good to see that the Octave function is close to R's. The test statistics `ks2stat` (maximum difference between empirical distribution functions) is the same in all functions. Matlab and R give the same `ks2stat` value; however, the corresponding `p` value is different. So I do not see what makes `kolmogorov_smirnov_test_2` correct and `kstest2` incorrect to compare with `ks.test`.

Comment: @Arpi You're welcome. All I know about the difference in the p-values is the part of the equation that is lambda for one and `sqrt(n)*d` for the other. I presume different statisticians found reasons to prefer one over the other and one package follows the original formulation and another follows a different one. That's the part where I have to suggest going to CV for further details though because it's more their domain than SO's. You could probably investigate the research papers the packages cite to find out tho. The `lambda` contains the `ks` as a part of it so it's probably newer.